# SQL Server query focusing on "pivoting" a table containing Non-numeric data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate, aggregate-functions

Table Name: Occupations

```
**Name  Occupation**  
Samantha    Doctor    
Julia   Actor
Maria   Actor
Meera   Singer
Ashely  Professor
Ketty   Professor
Christeen   Professor
Jane    Actor
Jenny   Doctor
Priya   Singer
```

---

The goal is to write a query that would "pivot" the aforementioned table data so that the following result would show up:

```
Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

I wrote the following query:

```
 WITH pivot_data AS
(
SELECT Occupation as Occupation1,  -- Grouping Column
Occupation, -- Spreading Column
Name -- Aggregate Column
FROM Occupations
)
SELECT  [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]
FROM pivot_data 
PIVOT (max(Name) 
       FOR Occupation IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor])
                                                            ) AS p;
```

Unfortunately, the aforementioned query gives the following incorrect result:

```
Doctor  Professor   Singer  Actor    
NULL    NULL    NULL    Maria    
Samantha    NULL    NULL    NULL    
NULL    Ketty   NULL    NULL    
NULL    NULL    Priya   NULL
```

Could someone please post a sql query that will show the desired result?(Also, it would be really helpful if you could do one query using the sql server "pivot" command, and another query withOut sql server "pivot" command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use pivot for this. Conditional aggregation is simpler to write and understand. It is also almost always slightly better for performance.

First I have to turn that data into something consumable. This is how you should post this kind of information in the future.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Name varchar(20)
    , Occupation varchar(20)
)

insert @Something values
('Samantha', 'Doctor')
, ('Julia', 'Actor')
, ('Maria', 'Actor')
, ('Meera', 'Singer')
, ('Ashely', 'Professor')
, ('Ketty', 'Professor')
, ('Christeen', 'Professor')
, ('Jane', 'Actor')
, ('Jenny', 'Doctor')
, ('Priya', 'Singer')
;
```

Now we can use this data to generate your output quite easily.

```
with NumberedRows as
(
    select * 
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Occupation order by name)
    from @Something
)

select Doctor = max(case when nr.Occupation = 'Doctor' then nr.Name end)
    , Professor = max(case when nr.Occupation = 'Professor' then nr.Name end)
    , Singer = max(case when nr.Occupation = 'Singer' then nr.Name end)
    , Actor = max(case when nr.Occupation = 'Actor' then nr.Name end)
from NumberedRows nr
group by nr.RowNum
```